# Xamarin.Forms and Firebase NuGet package

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add Firebase Crashlytics to a Xamarin.Forms application.  I see that Microsoft/Xamarin have created [NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Crash/70.1601.0-preview2) but the sample projects won't load, the NuGet package says it can't run with .NET 2 and there is no documentation.

Have you gotten this to work, and/or can you provide any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: That package is the `Xamarin.Android` Bindings as it contains Android native Java , you will need to install that into your Xamarin.Android application project, not the NetStd library project... The setup/initialization of Crashlytics is *typically* done in an Android Application subclass... (I use Crashlytics all the time, IMHO best crash reporter out there, and no one has a better analytics system)